# Can I check if the compass sensor is calibrated in UWP?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I was wondering if you can check if the compass sensor is calibrated in UWP c#. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The [`Magnetometer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.sensors.magnetometer.aspx) has a [`DirectionalAccuracy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.sensors.magnetometerreading.directionalaccuracy.aspx) that you can get by calling `GetCurrentReading`. You can use this to judge if calibration is required.

There's even [a video](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.sensors.magnetometeraccuracy.aspx) to show you what to do.